# Multiple items in array give coding-compliant error

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have a custom class which I store data in via NSUserDefaults. When I save one object into the array I can easily read it into my uitableview. It works perfectly. But as soon as there are more than 1 objects in the array I get the following error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSConcreteMutableData 0x7f8adad3a630> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fanLocation.'
```

The code for my class is the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MotileFavorite : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *favoriteName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *onNotificationsScreen;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fanLocation;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)favoriteName
     withLocation:(NSString*)fanLocation
     withIsOnNotificationsScreen:(NSString*)onNotificationsScreen;



@end
import "MotileFavorite.h"

@implementation MotileFavorite

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)favoriteName withLocation:(NSString *)fanLocation withIsOnNotificationsScreen:(NSString *)onNotificationsScreen
{
    self = [super init];
    self.favoriteName = favoriteName;
    self.fanLocation = fanLocation;
    self.onNotificationsScreen = onNotificationsScreen;

    return  self;
}
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.favoriteName forKey:@"favoriteName"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.fanLocation forKey:@"fanLocation"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.onNotificationsScreen forKey:@"onNotificationsScreen"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //decode properties, other class vars
        self.favoriteName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"favoriteName"];
        self.fanLocation = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"fanLocation"];
        self.onNotificationsScreen = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"onNotificationsScreen"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And the code for the table view is this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FavoritesListTableViewController : UITableViewController



@end

NSArray *favoritesArray;
NSArray *favoriteListNameArray;
NSArray *favoriteListLocationArray;
```

//the .m viewDidLoad is below where the error occurs

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSMutableArray *favoritesList = [defaults objectForKey:@"favoritesList"];
    NSMutableArray *unArchivedFavoritesList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:favoritesList.count];

    for (NSData *mfavObject in favoritesList) {
        NSData *mfUnEndocedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:mfavObject];
        [unArchivedFavoritesList addObject:mfUnEndocedObject];
    }



    favoriteListLocationArray = [unArchivedFavoritesList valueForKey:@"fanLocation"];

    favoriteListNameArray = [unArchivedFavoritesList valueForKey:@"favoriteName"];
}
```

The error occurs when trying to read to the favoriteListLocationArray. Here is the code when I save to the array:

```
- (IBAction)savePressed:(id)sender {

    if (_NotificationsSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        _notificationBool = @"Yes";

    }
    else{
        _notificationBool = @"No";
    }

    MotileFavorite *favorite = [[MotileFavorite alloc] initWithName:_nameFavoriteTextField.text withLocation:@"FANLOCATION" withIsOnNotificationsScreen:_notificationBool];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *favoritesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [defaults objectForKey:@"favoritesList"]];
    [favoritesList addObject:favorite];  

    NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:favoritesList.count];
    for (MotileFavorite *mfavObject in favoritesList) {
        NSData *mfEndocedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mfavObject];
        [archiveArray addObject:mfEndocedObject];
    }



    [defaults setObject:archiveArray forKey:@"favoritesList"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

I basically tried to do the "opposite" of saving it when I read it to the view but obviously that is not working for more than one value. Any idea what the code would be to make this work for multiple values in user defaults? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. You are sending `valueForKey:` to an NSData object. You can't do that.

Let's look at your code to see how that is happening. According to your own code, you are creating `unArchivedFavoritesList` as an NSArray of NSData objects:

```
NSData *mfUnEndocedObject = 
    [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:mfavObject];
[unArchivedFavoritesList addObject:mfUnEndocedObject];
```

Subsequently, you are calling `valueForKey:` on that array:

```
[unArchivedFavoritesList valueForKey:@"fanLocation"];
```

`valueForKey:` sent to an NSArray sends `valueForKey:` to each of the array's contained objects. But NSData objects do not respond to `valueForKey:`, so that makes no sense - and we crash.

EDIT: The reason this is happening turns out to be that you are archiving your objects before putting them into the array. That's not how archiving works. Archiving archives an object graph. You make your objects archivable and put the objects *themselves* into the array. Then you archive the array! The whole graph - the array and the objects - is archived for you. Now you have a reversible operation.

Comment: I was under the impression that "unarchiving" the object changed the objects back to the custom class. Is there an easy way to solve this problem? It seems strange that it works when there is only one object. Thank you for your response!

Comment: You have not given any relevant information. You are fetching something from user defaults via a key `"favoritesList"`. But I have no idea what you put in there to begin with. You do not show any code that puts anything into NSUserDefaults using that key. How can anyone possibly guess what you are doing? Use the debugger! It will show you what's going in and what's coming out.

Comment: In the meantime I believe I have answered your question. You asked for the meaning of the error message and I told you. I think we now know that what you are archiving/unarchiving is not what you think it is.

Comment: In a situation like this (where I still need help), would you suggest I edit my original question or ask a new one?

Comment: Go ahead and edit it. I can always delete my answer and try again! :) I probably should have tried to elicit more info by asking some questions in comments anyway...

Comment: I have edited my question! Thank you so much for spending time on me, I really really appreciate it!!

Comment: Okay, I see the problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68193/discussion-between-matt-and-user2547771).

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your MotileFavorite to have initWithCoder function to unarchive the data.

```
@implementation MotileFavorite

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        self.favoriteName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"favoriteName"];
        self.fanLocation = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"fanLocation"];
        self.onNotificationsScreen = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"fanLocation"];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Then do this to archive and unarchive it.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

MotileFavorite *m1 = [[MotileFavorite alloc] initWithName:@"A2"
                                             withLocation:@"A"
                              withIsOnNotificationsScreen:@"A"];
MotileFavorite *m2= [[MotileFavorite alloc] initWithName:@"A1"
                                            withLocation:@"A"
                             withIsOnNotificationsScreen:@"A"];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:m1,m2, nil];


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver
                                                  archivedDataWithRootObject:array]
                                          forKey:@"favoritesList"];

[defaults synchronize];

NSData *favouriteData = [defaults objectForKey:@"favoritesList"];
NSArray *unArchivedFavoritesList = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:favouriteData];


favoriteListLocationArray = [unArchivedFavoritesList valueForKey:@"fanLocation"];

favoriteListNameArray = [unArchivedFavoritesList valueForKey:@"favoriteName"];
```

`[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:]` generates an NSData object from the array. Save it in NSUserDefaults.

`initWithCoder` does the reverse of the encodeWithCoder function, to get back the object.

`[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]` get the array back from `NSData`.